# data-attribute not updating and onclick event still on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this onclick event effect : http://jsfiddle.net/WL6DX/1/

```
/* '#generateZip' */
$("#generateZip[data-readyzip='start']").click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        /* change style/css */
        $('#generateZip').addClass("disabled");
        $('#generateZip').html("<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin\"></i> in progress !");

        /* call the zip */
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/API/zipMC.php',
        timeout: 8000,
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            call: 'yes'
        },
        "success": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("AJAX success :) - statut " + textStatus);
            /* change attributs */
            $('#generateZip').attr('data-readyzip', 'yes');
            setTimeout(readyZip, 3000);
        },
        "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("AJAX fail :/ - statut " + textStatus);
            /* change attributs */
            $('#generateZip').attr('data-readyzip', 'no');
            setTimeout(readyZipFAIL, 3000);
        }
        });

});

/* readyZip() */
function readyZip() {
    $('#generateZip').removeClass("disabled btn-primary");
    $('#generateZip').addClass("btn-success");
    $('#generateZip').html("download is ready !");
    $('#generateZip').attr("href", "http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/resources/data/documentMC.zip")
}

/* readyZipFAIL() */
function readyZipFAIL() {
    $('#generateZip').removeClass("btn-primary");
    $('#generateZip').addClass("btn-danger");
    $('#generateZip').html("problem");
}
```

even if data-readyzip is updated to "yes" value, the onclick event is still on it and i fail to download my file ... what's wrong ?

Comment: event handlers are attached to **all elements that matches the selector at the time of binding**, changing the data attribute later doesn't remove the event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
$("#generateZip[data-readyzip='start']").click(function...
```

finds all of the relevant elements *as of when it was run* (and hooks up a click handler to them). It doesn't recheck them again later when you change things.

Two options:

1. If you like, you can use event delegation instead:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", "#generateZip[data-readyzip='start']", function...
   ```

   That hooks the `click` event on `document`, and then checks to see if it passed through any elements matching the selector while bubbling up to `document` from the element on which the event originated.

   `document` is, of course, a very deep level to be handling this. You might want to hook the event on a container closer to the element.
2. Since there's just one button, you can hook click on the button but only act on the click if it has the relevant attribute:

   ```
   $("#generateZip").click(function(e) {
       if ($(this).attr("data-readyzip") !== "start") {
           // Don't do it; prevent default or cancel bubbling if you like
           return;
       }
       // ...
   ```

Comment: two great options! a third option can be using `.on` and `.off` with namespaced events. e.g. `$('#generateZip').on('click.generate-zip', ...)` and `$('#generateZip').off('click.generate-zip')` in the ajax handlers